# Tie facebook user to application user

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I'm developing an android app and I've a working login system using JWT. The user can create an account on my server and can login using his own username/password after that.
I'd like to let the user login using Facebook, but I want his Facebook account to be tied to an account on my server.

I've added the facebook login button to my app, and I can access facebook name and email. Is it safe to use the facebook email like this?

- User login with facebook
- App gets facebook email address and sends it to the server
- Server checks if the email is already registered, if so server generates a JWT and the user is now logged in. If not the server creates a new account

Can I trust the email I get from the facebook login to authenticate the user or it can be tampered?
Is there any better way to achieve this? Thanks.

Edit: actually I know that sending just the email to my server wouldn't be safe. I was thinking about sending the Facebook access token too and then check on the server side if it's valid. Is this a good approach?
Also I don't need a working e-mail address from the user, I just need an unique identifier for each user.

Comment: Lots of users don’t even _have_ an email address on file with Facebook, because they only used their mobile to sign up.

Comment: Yes I've read that on the Facebook API docs. I was thinking about the unique username "@facebook.com" in case the user have no e-mail. I would like to know if I can trust what I get from Facebook login result or if there's a better way to tie a Facebook user to my server user.

Comment: The username@facebook.com thing has been deprecated a long time ago already; messages send there don’t go to the user’s inbox any more, there is only legacy support in that it forwards all incoming messages to the user’s external email ...

Comment: That wouldn't be a problem for my purpose, I just need something unique for each user that comes from Facebook. I've edited my question.

Comment: Yes, sending the token to the server is the usual approach. And for the unique value, simply take the app-scoped user id.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it working good using the user id.

Comment: Don't forget to validate the access token you are passed with Facebook.  If you don't make sure it's for your app and just check `/me` to verify the user, you could have anyone calling your api using tokens they get for their own facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

So to sum up:

- User logs in using the facebook button
- App sends user id and facebook access token to the server
- Server checks using facebook graphs api if the token is valid
- Server ties the facebook user id to a local account (creating a new account if necessary)